# Easiest way to calculate execution time of a python script?

Tags: python, performance-testing

What's the easiest way to calculate the execution time of a Python script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module is designed specifically for this purpose.

Silly example as follows

```
def test():
    """Stupid test function"""
    L = []
    for i in range(100):
        L.append(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from timeit import Timer
    t = Timer("test()", "from __main__ import test")
    print t.timeit()
```

> Note that timeit can also be used from the command line (python -m
>   timeit -s 'import module' 'module.test()') and that you can run the
>   statement several times to get a more accurate measurement. Something
>   I think time command doesn't support directly.
>    -- jcollado

Answer (score 5):

Using Linux `time` command like this : `time python file.py`

Or you can take the times at start and at end and calculate the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Under linux:
time python script.py

Answer (score 0):

How about using `time`?
example:
`time myPython.py`